# Link map state size and number of keys

Tags: apache-flink

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the total state size stored in the state backend.

I am currently using flink 1.3, above emr and rocksdb backend, with  asynchornous checkpointing and incremental checkpoints.

The flink dashboard under "checkpoints" displays the state size but I assume that due to the fact that I'm using incremental checkpoints I see in the checkpoint history page a fluctuation in state size.

The only current way I use and I'm not sure is a fit, is with "ls" command on the hdfs checkpoint location.

I assume there is a better way, and would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Currently one of the things that may help You with Your problem is `Queryable State` which allows You to basically query the state of the operator. But it is not available through the WEB-UI but you need to create a separate Queryable State Client for this. More info can be found [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html)